# Loop or map Core Data array to get every occurence of an object

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, loops, core-data

I would like to iterate through a `CoreData` `Managed Object` array to get every `code` occurence and call a `dataUpdate("\(code)")` function with each `code` string as a param.

```
func updateWalletValue() {

    // CryptosMO is the Managed Object containing `code` values among others (`amountValue` for example).
    var items : [CryptosMO] = []

    if CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        items = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
    }

    total = items.reduce(0.0, { $0 + Double($1.amountValue)! } )
    WalletTableViewController.staticTotal = total

    // What I am trying to do:
    for code in items.code {
        CryptoDataCall.init().dataUpdate("\(code)")
    }

}
```

**How can I access `code` occurences and use them in a loop or map them to call the function?**

Answer (score 1):

Okay found the solution myself :)

```
let codes = items.map { $0.code }
    for code in codes {
        CryptoDataCall.init().dataUpdate("\(code)")
    }
```

Comment: Correct, but it requires  an additional  array containing all the codes.

Comment: @MartinR isn't the `codes` array enough? My solution is working as is right now

Comment: As I said, your solution is correct (+1). But one can do without the additional `codes` array.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `items` array, and access the `code` member in
the closure:

```
for items in items { item in 
    // do something with `item.code` ...
}
```

Or with shorthand parameter names:

```
for items in items { 
    // do something with `$0.code` ...
}
```

Or with `forEach`:

```
items.forEach {
    // do something with `$0.code` ...
}
```